# General Questions about List

Tags: c#

Hi
I have a general question about Lists in C#.
Here is my Code:

```
public List<string> Example()
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus");

        List<string> output = new List<string>();

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            output.Add(System.Convert.ToString(queryObj["InstanceName"]));
        }

        return output;
    }
```

and now I want to give the first input out

```
public FormMain()
    {

        Debug.WriteLine(Example(1));


    }
```

No overload for method 'output' takes 1 arguments

I hope you can explain me this and sorry for my question, I am an absoltue beginner

Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well output is a List. Since you have coded Example as a method, which returns a list, to access it you need to call it using method syntax with empty parentheses.  The return value is an instance of a `List<string>`.  If you hit the decimal point after typing `Example()` you will see in intellisense the members of this object. One of them will show as square brackets like this `[]`. this is the member you need to use to access whatever you have put in the list. The values you would provide are zero-based, that is they start at zero (for the first item in the list), and increase from there.  So to access the first item in the list, you would write:

`Debug.WriteLine(Example()[1]);`

using the square brackets, not parentheses.  You still need the parentheses in Example(), because it is a method...  If you recoded it as a property:

```
public List<string> Example    
{     
   get 
   {   
      ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
        new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", 
          "SELECT * FROM MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus");        
      List<string> output = new List<string>();        
      foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
          output.Add(System.Convert.ToString(queryObj["InstanceName"]));  
      return output;
   }            
}
```

Then you would not need those parentheses and could just write

`Debug.WriteLine(Example[1]);`

Answer (score 1):

try:

`Debug.WriteLine(Example()[1]);`

**EDIT:**
if you are looking for the first element you should use **0** rather than **1** as others pointed out.

Comment: 1 is also working because there are more than one member in the list (i know that the list is starting with 0) but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
using System.Linq;

public List<string> Example()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus");

    return searcher.Get().ToList();
}

public void Test()
{
    var myList = Example();
    var element = myList[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
Example()[0];
```

The method `Example()` returns a `List<string>`, you can visit its elements by index directly, something like `mylist[0]`. And the first element has the index 0 instead of 1 in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Bolu's answer was good, except it should be a 0 instead of a 1 - c# List and arrays are zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you get is: `No overload for method 'Example' takes 1 arguments` not `No overload for method 'output' takes 1 arguments`.

It denotes that the method `Example` is not prepared to take 1 argument.

to be able to do that:

```
Debug.WriteLine(Example()[0]);
```

Since you said the first output, that's why the index is zero here.